# Is Kafka suitable for running a public API?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have an event stream that I want to publish. It's partitioned into topics, continually updates, will need to scale horizontally (and not having a SPOF is nice), and may require replaying old events in certain circumstances. All the features that seem to match Kafka's capabilities.

I want to publish this to the world through a public API that anyone can connect to and get events. Is Kafka a suitable technology for exposing as a public API?

I've read the Documentation page, but not gone any deeper yet. ACLs seem to be sensible.

My concerns

1. Consumers will be anywhere in the world. I can't see that being a problem seeing Kafka's architecture. The rate of messages probably won't be more than 10 per second.
2. Is integration with zookeeper an issue?
3. Are there any arguments against letting subscriber clients connect that I don't control?

Comment: Personally, I would use another system to front-end it. In fact, I do. I use NodeJS to handle the communications with the clients, and `kafka-node` to handle communications between Kafka and Node. Amongst other things, I remember reading "no one uses ACLs" somewhere, which would make me concerned about relying on them -- lack of use equals high likelihood of being buggy. There are also firewall / security issues you are likely to run into. I know this isn't the answer you are looking for -- hence it's a comment.

Comment: No, that's exactly the answer I'm looking for, thank you. What are you doing the other wide of Node? Websockets? Can you resume broken streams?

Comment: I use `engine.io`. I originally used `socket.io` and websockets, but dropped down to a lower level because I didn't need the overhead. I'm not using auto-reconnect at this point -- but you can do it with `engine.io`. Then it's just a matter of tagging your client with a `client-id` and keeping the context with `localStorage` on the client side and in a `Map()` on the NodeJS server side.

Comment: There's a very simple example of a socket.io server reading from a kafka topic here: https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/ksql-workshop/websockets/index.js

Answer (score 0):

> 3. Are there any arguments against letting subscriber clients connect that I don't control?

One of the issues that I would consider is possible `group.id` collisions.

Let's say that you have one single topic to be used by the world for consuming your messages.

Now if one of your clients has a multi-node system and wants to avoid reading the same message twice, they would set the same `group.id` to both nodes, forming a consumer group.

But, what if someone else in the world uses the same `group.id`? They would affect the first client, causing it to lose messages. There seems to be no security at that level.