# Exposing Kafka as a public API

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a REST API that I want to augment with a streaming event log that can be replayed. I was wondering if there is any good way of opening up Kafka for this kind of "public" consumption. Kafka essentially offers all the consumer APIs I'm planning, so it would be nice not to reinvent the wheel.

API users register for an API key, so it's possible to do some authentication/permission management. However, I cannot control whether users attempt malicious behaviour.

I've found [this related StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600237/is-kafka-suitable-for-running-a-public-api), but it is outdated and doesn't have any answers.

Comment: While not a good idea without authentication, have you tried using the Kafka REST proxy? Otherwise, it's not clear what you're expecting to get, as Kafka is meant for unbounded data feeds... You could also search elsewhere for SSE+Kafka, also "Pushpin" service

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. Like Kafka itself, the Kafka REST proxy isn't advertised as suitable for public consumption – has anyone tried that? (E.g., is it safe from malicious behaviour?) SSE and Pushpin look interesting, but I'm not convinced they can accommodate Kafka-like behaviour like exactly-once/at-least-once delivery and "replaying" a log from the beginning (at least not without some tricky customization).

Comment: I imagine if you setup proper SASL/SSL policies around either tool, you could expose them externally, though once the key is exposed, you're out of luck (but that's not unique to Kafka). What you're proposing doesn't sound much different that what AWS Cloudwatch/Kinesis (or other hosted MQ tech) could provide, and those are publicly consumable via a key. CloudKaraka for example, uses SASL_SCRAM https://www.cloudkarafka.com/docs-kafkacat.html